# How do I design a trigger for Postgresql, and what is wrong with my "Hello world" test?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, triggers, sql-insert, ddl

I need to use triggers in postgresql (preferably via SQLALchemy ORM). However, I can't seem to get to first base with creating one.
As a basic test, I am trying to put the string "Hello world" into a column called test each time a row is inserted.

I set up my tables like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String, CheckConstraint, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDL
import datetime

dbUrl = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

engine = create_engine(dbUrl,
                       echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()



class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
  pass

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    managers: Mapped[List[Manager]] = relationship(back_populates="company")

Company.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    type: Mapped[str]
    test: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "employee",
        "polymorphic_on": "type",
    }

Employee.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "manager"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
    manager_name: Mapped[str]
    CheckConstraint("manager_name == employee.name", name="check1")

    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
    company: Mapped[Company] = relationship(back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "manager",
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "engineer"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name: Mapped[str]

    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
    company: Mapped[Company] = relationship(back_populates="engineers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "engineer",
    }  
Engineer.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

and then tried to creat a trigger like this:

```
sqlalchemy.event.listen(metadata,
                       "before_create",
                       DDL("""CREATE TRIGGER autoCreateEmployee
                       AFTER INSERT
                       ON employee
                       FOR EACH ROW
                       INSERT INTO employee(test)
                       VALUES("Hello world"),
                       0)  
                       """))
```

The tables were created and no error was emitted, but as far as I can tell, the trigger was not added. I also tried running my test trigger statement directly in SQL using DBeaver:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoCreateEmployee
                       AFTER INSERT
                       ON employee
                       FOR EACH ROW
                       INSERT INTO employee(test)
                       VALUES("Hello world")
```

That gave me this error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Position: 165

Error position: line: 5 pos: 164
```

What is wrong with my trigger statement? And why don't I see the error when running via SQLAlchemy?

Edit: I was attempting to adapt this example:
[image]

Update: Based on the comments, I've taken another look at the docs and realized that some of the examples I were looking at weren't even Postgres. Now I can run the commands to create a function and trigger without error, but as far as I can tell, the trigger exists (as I cannot re-create it without deleting), but doesn't appear to be associated with the table it's supposed to be on.

At the moment I am just running raw SQL to avoid ORM complications:

```
drop function hello_world;

CREATE FUNCTION hello_world() RETURNS trigger AS $hello_world$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO employee(test) VALUES ("HELLO WORLD!");
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$hello_world$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

drop trigger hello on employee;

CREATE TRIGGER hello
    AFTER UPDATE ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION hello_world();
```

Edit2: Deleted a screenshot because it was the wrong screenshot and based on a misunderstanding anyway.

Current status:

My function is like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $hello_world$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO employee(test) VALUES ('HELLO WORLD!');
    END;
$hello_world$
```

and I create my trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hello
    AFTER INSERT ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION hello_world();
```

However, it tries to create a NEW row with just the test string in the test column instead of into the row on which I just entered data. I was under the impression that the `FOR EACH ROW` meant that the function will be carried out on all rows being inserted. Obviously I am still missing something.

If I run:

```
INSERT INTO employee (name,type) VALUES ('Merv', 'manager');
```

I get

```
SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: null value in column "name" of relation "employee" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (31, null, null, HELLO WORLD!).
  Where: SQL statement "INSERT INTO employee(test) VALUES ('HELLO WORLD!')"
PL/pgSQL function hello_world() line 3 at SQL statement
```

So now I need to figure out how to target the just-modified row(s) with the trigger function.

Comment: The `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is incorrect - it must call a trigger function. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to give me a hint as to what is incorrect about it? I did look at the documentation. As far as I can tell, my statement is in the same format as the examples here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: I don't see `... EXECUTE FUNCTION funcname()`. You cannot use `INSERT` instead. You have to write a trigger function that performs the `INSERT`, then you have to use the function to define the trigger. [There are examples in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE)

Comment: I was also using a lesson that shows an example that that does not use `EXECUTE FUNCTION`, this one: https://learn.percipio.com/courses/775cbc38-0635-4616-a37c-f673abd232ff/videos/889b3e74-fe0e-476b-89fc-90ae1fb0efe3

Thanks for linking to some more examples, but I still don't understand how I know what can and cannot be used in a trigger.

Comment: If you want to avoid such confusion, always believe the PostgreSQL documentation rather than questionable tutorials. What is not allowed by the PostgreSQL syntax is forbidden.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe well could you please say what is not allowed instead of making me read the documentation and guess? Can you show me what in that link should make this all clear to me? I don't doubt that the answer is in there but perhaps you, an expert, could help me see it.

Comment: Sorry, this is a forum for answering questions, not for writing tutorials. I cannot make it any clearer than the documentation already is.

Comment: You have been told what the problem is and pointed at the docs that show the proper method, now it is time you do the homework. Hint: look at *Description* and *Examples* sections at [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, no, I haven't been told what the problem is. It's not at all clear to me from the documentation how to extrapolate to creating my own triggers. Does every single trigger require `EXECUTE FUNCTION`? If so, why do so many tutorials have examples without it?

Comment: Here is another example not using `EXECUTE FUNCTION`: http://nowfromhome.com/posts/postgres-triggers-functions-sequences/

Comment: 1) You are using Postgres so you need to stick to Postgres docs and examples. Other databases do things differently. 2) Your second link uses `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` which is allowed per the docs [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html): *In the syntax of CREATE TRIGGER, the keywords FUNCTION and PROCEDURE are equivalent, but the referenced function must in any case be a function, not a procedure. The use of the keyword PROCEDURE here is historical and deprecated.*  3) Bottom line read the Postgres `create trigger` docs top to bottom.

Comment: I see what you two are saying now and got a little further on that basis. Unfortunately I'm still trying to figure out how to get this working.

Comment: 1) The table it is associated with is determined by `AFTER UPDATE ON employee`, so the `employee` table. Your screenshot(FYI, **do not use images**) shows you looking at the `manager` table. 2) `AFTER UPDATE ON employee` and a trigger statement `INSERT INTO employee(test) ... RETURN NEW;`  does not make sense. 3) Read [plpgsql Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: Yeah, I posted a screenshot of the wrong table, but the actual employee table looked the same. My problem there was that I didn't realize the the commands were going to an entirely different database, to which I had forgotten I was also connected. Sorry about being flaky in this thread, I blame the Adderall shortage.

Comment: Again: 3) Read [plpgsql Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for my trigger. Thank you all for your patience.

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $hello_world$
    BEGIN
        NEW.test := 'HeLLo wErLd';
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$hello_world$


CREATE TRIGGER hello
    BEFORE INSERT ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION hello_world();
```

Comment: There needs to be a `;` after `$hello_world$` otherwise the function will not be created.

Comment: Thanks, I think my SQL editor/IDE (DBeaver) just silently took care of that.

Answer (score -2):

Might be because of double quotes. Generally, double quotes are for names of tables or fields & the single quotes are for string constants.

Try this:

```
sqlalchemy.event.listen(metadata,
                       "before_create",
                       DDL("""CREATE TRIGGER autoCreateEmployee
                       AFTER INSERT
                       ON employee
                       FOR EACH ROW
                       INSERT INTO employee(test)
                       VALUES('Hello world'),
                       0)  
                       """))
```

and this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoCreateEmployee
                       AFTER INSERT
                       ON employee
                       FOR EACH ROW
                       INSERT INTO employee(test)
                       VALUES('Hello world')
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that was not the issue.

Comment: The `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is as wrong as in the question.

Comment: Not an a correct answer either correct or delete.